# Oracle dba_tab_cols query

Tags: oracle

Hi is it possible to retrieve the primary key and unique key using the dba_tab_cols query?

Is there any query that allows me to retrieve all of the following fields?

- Column Name
- Data Type
- Primary Key
- Null/Not Null
- Unique Key
- Default Value
- Extra

Answer (score 2):

Both primary and unique keys can span more than one column, so they wouldn't belong in `dba_tab_columns`. You'd need to look at `dba_constraints` and `dba_cons_columns` to get that information.

This is a starting point, maybe:

```sql
select owner, table_name, column_name, data_type, primary_key,
  nullable, unique_key, data_default
from (
  select dtc.owner, dtc.table_name, dtc.column_id, dtc.column_name,
    dtc.data_type, dtc.nullable, dtc.data_default,
    case when dc.constraint_type = 'P' and dcc.column_name = dtc.column_name
      then dc.constraint_name end as primary_key,
    case when dc.constraint_type = 'U' and dcc.column_name = dtc.column_name
      then dc.constraint_name end as unique_key,
    row_number() over (partition by dtc.owner, dtc.table_name, dtc.column_id
      order by null) as rn
  from dba_tab_columns dtc
  left join dba_constraints dc
  on dc.owner = dtc.owner
  and dc.table_name = dtc.table_name
  and dc.constraint_type in ('P', 'U')
  left join dba_cons_columns dcc
  on dcc.owner = dc.owner
  and dcc.constraint_name = dc.constraint_name
  and dcc.table_name = dc.table_name
  and dcc.column_name = dtc.column_name
  where dtc.owner = '<owner>'
  and dtc.table_name = '<table_name>'
)
where rn = 1
order by owner, table_name, column_id;
```

I've done this with a subquery that generates a `row_number` value because you'd get duplicates for a table with more than one constraint; and because you want the default value, which is a `long` (column `data_default`), you can't use `distinct` or `group by`. It feels a bit inelegant, but I'm sure you can work on it to get what you need.

It's also possible to have a check constraint that replicates the `not null` version, though it isn't advisable. And a unique index won't show up as a unique constraint, so you might want to look for one of those too, via `dba_indexes` and `dba_ind_columns`. An index used to back up a unique constrain will appear in both, though.

You could look at `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` to get this information too, depending on what you intend to do with it. I'm not sure why this would be useful, other than to try to recreate the schema elsewhere, and there are better tools for doing that.